# Prove double negation introduction WITHOUT elimination, in a propositional logic axiom system.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, formal-proofs

I'm looking for a proof in classical propositional logic of "double negation introduction" (Q⊢¬¬Q) *without* using double negation elimination (¬¬Q⊢Q).

I'm using the Hilbert system with the following axioms:

1. X→(Y→X)
2. (X→(Y→Z))→((X→Y)→(X→Z))
3. (¬Y→¬X)→(X→Y)

Use uniform substitution and Modes Ponens as rule of inference. Deduction Theorem also allowed.

Prove (Q⊢¬¬Q) without assuming (¬¬Q⊢Q). Thanks!

**Remark:** I know that this is possible, by the fact that only (Q⊢¬¬Q) is valid in intuitionistic logic; (¬¬Q⊢Q) is not. Therefore one should be able to derive (Q⊢¬¬Q) without using (¬¬Q⊢Q) since the former, and not the latter, holds in weaker systems than classical logic. However, all the proofs I've seen so far use (¬¬Q⊢Q).

Comment: Number 3 isn't a valid principle either in intuitionistic logic...

Comment: In a system where $\lnot P \overset{def}{=} (P \rightarrow \bot)$ this is trivial (even without using an explosion principle): $Q, \lnot Q \vdash \bot$ by Modus Ponens on assumptions $Q \rightarrow \bot$ and $Q$, so the Deduction Theorem would imply $Q \vdash (\lnot Q \rightarrow \bot)$.

Comment: Perhaps I ought to remove the remark then, and just ask:

Can anyone give a proof in classical logic, using the axioms given, for (Q⊢¬¬Q) without assuming (¬¬Q⊢Q)?

Comment: @Tangent $(\lnot Y \to \lnot X) \to (X \to Y)$ is not valid in intuitionistic logic, so there is no proof using the above axioms which entirely avoids classical theorems.  One thing that might work to avoid DNE is:  **(1.)** combined with **(3)** gives $\lnot X \to (X \to Y)$ (the principle of explosion), equivalently $X \to (\lnot X \to Y)$.  Then if you could prove $(W \to \lnot W) \to \lnot W$, then you could prove your theorem using $X = Q, W = \lnot Q, Y = \lnot \lnot Q$.

Comment: Can ($\lnot$$\lnot$X$\rightarrow$X) get used in the proof?