# Propositional logic without rules of inference and assumptions (except MP)

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, hilbert-calculus

I was wondering whether it would be possible to do propositional logic without any rules of inference and assumptions (except modus ponens).

I have the following axioms:

1. $ p \to (q \to p) $
2. $ (p \to (q \to r)) \to ((p \to q) \to (p \to r)) $
3. $ (\lnot p \to \lnot q) \to (q \to p) $
4. MP: From $ p $ and $ p \to q $, infer $ q $.

The other connectives ($ \lor $ and $ \land $) are defined like this:

$ p \lor q := \lnot p \to q $

$ p \land q := \lnot (p \to \lnot q) $

For example, [double negation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negation#Proofs) uses [hypothetical syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothetical_syllogism): from $ p \to q $ and $ q \to r $, infer $ p \to r $.

Moreover, I can't find proofs for (or prove myself) common rules of inference in natural deduction, such as:

- $ (p \to q) \to (\lnot q \to \lnot p) $
- $ p \to \lnot \lnot p $
- $ p \to (p \lor q) $
- $ (p \land q) \to p $
- $ ((p \to q) \land (q \to r)) \to (p \to r) $

My question is whether it is possible to not use rules of inference and assumptions (except MP) in propositional logic, or that you can't prove these statements without them.

I found this question, but it does not have any answers yet: [Prove double negation introduction WITHOUT elimination, in a propositional logic axiom system.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2468217/prove-double-negation-introduction-without-elimination-in-a-propositional-logic)

### Example proof

I hope this clarifies some things, here's something that I managed to prove:

1. $ p \to ( p \to p ) $ (Axiom 1)
2. $ p \to ( ( p \to p ) \to p ) $ (Axiom 1)
3. $ ( p \to ( ( p \to p ) \to p ) ) \to ( ( p \to ( p \to p ) ) \to ( p \to p ) ) $ (Axiom 2)
4. $ ( p \to ( p \to p ) ) \to ( p \to p ) $ (MP 2, 3)
5. $ p \to p $ (MP 1, 4)

Comment: As PW_246 pointed out, that Hilbert system is sound and complete for PL. In case you are looking for proofs, Metamath's [pmproofs.txt](https://us.metamath.org/mmsolitaire/pmproofs.txt) database uses the same axioms. To parse its [condensed detachment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condensed_detachment) proofs into formula-based proofs, you can use the [pmGenerator](https://github.com/xamidi/pmGenerator) tool, e.g. `pmGenerator --parse D3DD2DD2D13DD2D1311 -u` prints a proof for $ p \to \lnot \lnot p $.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the axiom set you listed is sound and complete for classical propositional logic. In order to add expressivity, one may use other operators such as $\lor$, $\land$ and $\leftrightarrow$.

If you don’t want to add any other axioms, then you’d need to define the other operators as a shorthand for formulas already expressible with $\to$ and $\neg$. For example, $(p \lor q):=(\neg p \to q)$, and $(p \land q):=\neg (p \to \neg q)$.

If you count using definitions as being an inference rule, then you won’t be able to actually prove the formulas with different operators in the calculus defined by the mentioned axioms. In that case, you’d have to prove the version using only negation and implication, and then operate at a meta-level to get the exact formula you want. Otherwise, you’d have to add axioms for the other operators.

Comment: Hi, yes I forgot to add the definitions for logical disjunction and conjunction. I added these to my post now. Having these defined, one can always write each formula using only negation and implication. What exactly do you mean by meta-level, could you please give an example of how that would work?

Comment: It just depends on whether you think the substitution occurs within the propositional calculus itself, or if it happens at the meta-level. For example, many proof systems use axiom schemas, but another option would be to actually have uniform substitution as an inference rule and use axioms as opposed to an axiom schema. In the same way, whether an instance of a substitution of a formula for its definition via other operators is an inference rule or meta-theorem depends on how the system is defined.

Comment: I use axiom schemes, so every variable (wff) may be substituted by another wff. Note that if p and q are wffs, so are not-p and p-implies-q. I added a theorem that I already managed to prove, hope it helps.

Comment: To be fair, finding proofs in a straight-up axiomatic system is usually tricky, so don’t be worried you can’t find proofs for the ones you posted. I would suggest looking at the Wikipedia article on the Deduction Theorem so you can turn any deduction in a Hilbert-style system into an axiomatic proof. Bram28’s answer in this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3661388/proving-vdash-neg-neg-p-to-p-in-first-order-logic-preferrably-without-ded provides a very clear and in-depth example of how to convert a deduction into an axiomatic proof, and there is a similarly helpful one on wiki.

Comment: I've never heard of the Deduction Theorem, but it is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much!